# Why do not resolved dependency by name?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a named dependency:

```
kernel.Bind<IManager>().To<Manager>().Named("Registration").WithConstructorArgument("settings", new Custom1SettingsA());
kernel.Bind<IManager>().To<Manager>().Named("Login").WithConstructorArgument("settings", new Custom1SettingsB());
```

However, the code does not work. In fact, the code got just the first dependency:

```
kernel.Bind<IHandler>().To<Handler>().WithConstructorArgument("manager", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IManager>("Registration"));
```

I created the dependency in another way, but it is very big:

```
kernel.Bind<IHandler>().To<Handler>().
    WithConstructorArgument("manager", ctx =>
        ctx.Kernel.Get<IManager>(
            metadata => metadata.Name.Equals("Registration")));
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of ninject are you using? The named resolution should work

Comment: I use last version Version 3.0